# Include Variable value in date pipe in Kendo (Dynamic format) : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, scope, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Column for date value, There we have used a pipe like this at template property inside the below column.

Now i want to change the format of kendo grid column according to the date format

My Problem/Question :- I am retrieving Date format such as dd-MM-yyyy or MM-dd-yyyy or dd-MM-yy or MM-dd-yy from localStorage which is dynamic according to the user preference.

But whenever i use that variable in the template (containing date format ex: dd-MM-yyyy) in place of the default date pipe having same format of default date pipe, kendo Do not accept it and gives the error : Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined kendo

```
const myDateFormat = this.$localStorage.dateFormat;   
function getDefaultColumns($translate) {
        return [
            {
              field: 'INVOICE_DATE',
              title: $translate.instant('invoiceDate'),
              headerTemplate: '{{ \'invDate\' | translate }}',
              template: '{{ dataItem.INVOICE_DATE | date: \'yyyy-MM-dd\' }}',//i am using the localStorage value here 
              filterable: {
                ui(element) {
                  element.kendoDatePicker({
                    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                  });
                }
              },
              width: 100
            }
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Scopes between kendo and angularjs are kind of tricky, could you please try just printing _dateFormat_ ? What is the result?

Comment: If i use the dateFormat like this date: dateFormat, it do not detect the variable dateFormat as i am using visual studio code and it says that dateFormat is declared but never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want with a ES2015 Template String.

Consider this modification to your program listing:

```
function getDefaultColumns($translate) {
    let dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
    return [
    {
          field: 'INVOICE_DATE',
          title: $translate.instant('invoiceDate'),
          headerTemplate: '{{ \'invDate\' | translate }}',
          template: `{{ dataItem.INVOICE_DATE | date: \'${dateFormat}\' }}`,
          filterable: {
            ui(element) {
              element.kendoDatePicker({
                format: dateFormat
              });
            }
          },
          width: 100
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it but i think because of kendo it says  "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Comment: Sorry, this is the best I can do without more information.  Consider editing your question to include a runnable snippet.  Then I can tweak your snippet until it works.

Comment: The ES2015 Template String made it work, i was not applying the ` , in starting and ending.